# Time or Datepicker inside Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

during the last week I was trying to put datapicker inside all datatabels rows.

I found many solutions but none of them worked with me!

any one have a complete solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "datapicker" means "datepicker"

Well you can integrate your datepicker(I personally use Bootstrap datepicker) in `DataTable` pretty easily.

Create the column for your datepicker and add it dynamically at creation of table like below.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/q62ttLL0/1/

Considering you have the table definition as :

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Select Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

With input data as

```
var inputData = [
    ["Prakash", "Software Analyst", 5000],
    ["Akshay", "Software Analyst", 6000]
  ]
```

Now initialize the `DataTable` and `datepicker`

```
var exampleTable = $('#example').DataTable( {
  "data": inputData,
  "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": -1,
                "data": null,
                "orderable": false,
                "defaultContent": ['<input type="text" class="form-control datePicker" placeholder="Date" />']
            }]
} );


$(".datePicker").datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'                                           
});
```

Comment: doesnt work if you go to page 2 , any solution for that ?